# How to parse a SOAP file using xmllint or xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, soap, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet, xmllint

I have the following SOAP file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <auth:Session xmlns:auth="http://www" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
      <auth:IPAddress>1111</auth:IPAddress>
    </auth:Session>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <auth:SessionT xmlns:auth="http://www.">result</auth:SessionT>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and I want to get result.
I have tried different ways but every time I get the same error
**"Namespace prefix auth on SessionT is not defined"**.

Here it is one of the commands I've tried:
`xmlstarlet sel -t -v /auth:SessionT test.xml`

Br,
JD

Answer (score 1):

With `xmlstarlet`, provide the namespace present in the source document using the `-N` option:

```sh
$ xmlstarlet sel -N auth="http://www." -t -v "//auth:SessionT" test.xml
result
```

Using `xmllint`, you could instead simply use `local-name()` to just check the tag name:

```sh
$ xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name() = "SessionT"]/text()' test.xml
result
```

Not tagged, but yet another alternative would be using `xq` (a `jq` wrapper provided with [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)) like this:

```sh
$ xq -r '.. | ."auth:SessionT"? // empty | ."#text"' test.xml
result
```